# Kentico visitor site language is not changing according to browser language setting

Tags: localization, multilingual, kentico

Here I am facing a strange issue. I have developed a site in Kentico and have added en-US and sv-SE cultures to site. I have made us-EN as default content culture and I have set "Visitor Culture" to Automatic.

Wherever Visitor setting are there, I have set them to automatic.

In IE I have only sv-SE in language list. When I open the site in IE, It is not opening site in sv-SE culture. It is opening in en-US culture. I cleared cache, cleared browser .did everything but site is not opening using browser language setting.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go again through the documentation 
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Setting+default+languages+for+users+and+visitors

Comment: I have followed everything that is mentioned in the link  mivra sent. but still site is not opening using browser settings.